# number of parameters in Bayes Net

Tags: bayesian-network

This might be a bit rudimentary. Have some problems in understanding the number of parameters in Bayes Net

[image: The interview Bayes Network]

> How do we calculate the number of parameters in the Bayes net in the
>   preceding  diagram? Let's go through each conditional probability
>   table, one parameter at a  time. Experience and Grades take two
>   values, and therefore need one independent  parameter each. The
>   Interview table has 12 (3 x 4) parameters. However, each row  sums up
>   to 1, and therefore, we need two independent parameters per row. The 
>   whole table needs 8 (2 x 4) independent parameters. Similarly, the
>   Offer table has six entries, but only 1 independent parameter per row
>   is required, which makes 3 (1 x 3) independent parameters. Therefore,
>   the total number of parameters is 1 (Experience) + 1 (Grades)+ 12
>   (Interview) + 3 (Offer) amount to 17, which is a lot lesser than 24
>   parameters to fully specify the joint distribution. Therefore, the
>   independence assumptions in the Bayesian network helps us avoid
>   specifying the joint distribution.

I can understand

- that the total number of parameters is 24 without reduction
- the number independent parameters for each row in interview table is 2
- the number independent parameters for each row in job offer table is 1

What I cannot understand is why in the final calculation the number of parameters to define interview table is 12 instead of 8?

Can I seek your help in understanding this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/slides/GrMod1_2_8_2011-ann.pdf
at page seventeen you find what you are looking for

Comment: Its not advisable to post answers as links as they will eventually become deprecated